# Is any tiny library in javascript (for node) for ignore files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like implement a ingnore file in my node script like .ignore

exemple .projectignore:

```
file*
dir/*
dir/**/dir
*.swp
```

and with a with a javascript function

```
fs.readdir("/", function(err, files){
  if(!FileLib.isIgnored(files){
    ...
  }
});
```

Is any library can do this or how i can implement it easily ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [`glob`](https://npmjs.org/package/glob) and [`minimatch`](https://npmjs.org/package/minimatch) packages.